# Re-Installing IPhone App From Inside The App

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to find a way if it's possible to re-install an IPhone app from inside it?

Let's say my users have the app already installed in their phones and now new version is released, can I make my app such that it will check over internet if new version is available and if it is, download it and ask the user to install it. If user says yes, it will first un-install the current version and will install downloaded version.

Is it possible anyhow?

Comment: Unless you were unaware of its existence, why would you want to circumvent the current new version upgrade installation process Apple already built into the iTunes App Store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably not because to uninstall an app it requires the app to be closed

Answer (score 5):

Apple wont allow this.

- For one reason, un-installing the app removes all the user documents (if applicable), so theres no way to preserve user data.
- Apple already has a medium for updating (iTunes App Store).

If you want to be able to check if there is a newer version of your app, you can do that simply by checking a text file *(for example)* on your server, and notifying *(by `UIAlertView` possibly)* the user that there is a newer version of your app. But again, Apple already has a standard system in place. *(Badges on the App Store icon)*

Comment: +1, I would add that if there was an "upgrade now" option UIAlert view, one could link to their app in iTunes which would take them to the app in the iPhone's App Store.

Comment: You could also add a button that launches the user into your app in the App Store if theres an update, yes, thats a good option too.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to do that. If you upload a new version to the app store, a notification badge will appear on the app store icon on your users' phones. You aren't allowed to install apps any other way than through the app store, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your app and what you want to update. It's not possible to reinstall the native app, but you can download data and update your app using that data. For example, we have an app in the store which is mainly a webview inside the native app. The first time it launches, it uses the internal data, but checks our server if there is an update. If there is an update, it downloads remote data and replaces the internal. It's what most magazines do for updating their libraries.